# change page layout dynamically in Liferay

Tags: layout, liferay, liferay-6

Can anyone please tell me how to dynamically change page layout in Liferay.
Let's consider we have page with Layout 2 column(50/50) and both these columns have portlets.
If a user clicks on any of the portlets, I Would like to change the page layout to 2 column(70/30).

Comment: I believe if you click a portlet you can maximize it instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply...but i would like to show two portlet on same page and if i change the state to maximize it will only show one portlet on page

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it but did you try checking `LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout()` ?

That should help you. If you are creating a new page use `LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout()` otherwise use `updateLayout()`.

Get layout and then update it.

```
layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(groupId, false, friendlyURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to-
As provided-

layoutId = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(groupId, false, friendlyURL);

pass the new page's friendlyURL,
if it is a public page then false else true for private,
and make sure that you have applied some layout to the new page(for e.g- 70/30)

Use this layoutId in -

" windowState="<%= WindowState.NORMAL.toString()%>">

provide portletId to the portletname field.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample html portion from a layout template...

```
<div class="portlet-layout">
    <div class="aui-w70 portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-2">
        $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
    </div>
    <div class="aui-w30 portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-3">
        $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
    </div>
</div>
```

if you check it minutely, there are classes describing the width of the div, In my example aui-w70 is for width 70% and aui-w30 is for 30%. I am sure you will also get similar things in your layout too. 
If you can change the class names according to your need in desired events, you are good to go...
Give it a try....